# Whats the most efficient way of doing this?

Tags: java, arrays, iteration

I've got an array `array` of size N. For every 3 indexes in it I want to take them out and declare and assign those values to another array of size 3. I then want to go back to that array and take the next 3 and put it in a different array of size 3. I'll iterate like this for 3 different arrays of size 3 `a1,a2,a3` once this is done I want to empty `a1,a2,a3` and re add the NEXT 3 values to the 3 arrays of size 3 repeating this on till we reach `array.length`

What would be the best / most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Is the size N garuanteed to be a multiple of 3 (or 9 for that matter?)

Comment: a more precise topic would be more efficient, too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int i=0; i<=N-9; i+=9) {
 System.arrayCopy(arrayN, i, a1, 0, 3);
 System.arrayCopy(arrayN, i+3, a2, 0, 3);
 System.arrayCopy(arrayN, i+6, a3, 0, 3);
 // presumably do other stuff here
}
```

That's a pretty brittle but fast way of doing it.  Each time the previous values are overwritten, so no need to clear.  If you do need to have `arrayN` clear, you can just `Arrays.fill(arrayN, null)` after the loop.

EDIT: For the less brittle answer, I'm going to assume you'd be inflating m x n arrays.  Instead of hard coding a1, a2, ... am, make a 2D array `a[m][n]`.

```
for (i=0; i<=N-m*n; i+=m*n) {
 for (int j=0; j<m; j++) System.arrayCopy(arrayN, i+n*j, a[j], 0, n);
 // presumably do other stuff here
}
```

and, as Adrian suggests in the comments, declare `i` outside the loop and use its value relative to N to deal with leftovers as appropriate.

Comment: +1 it was what I had in mind when I commented on the question.

Comment: @Adrian: this should satisfy the wrong length problem, provided the correct response is to not barf and work with as much of the array as possible.  Alternately, if somehow N is known to be a multiple of 9, the loop control could be modified to just `i<N`.

Comment: You could declare 'i' outside the loop and perform a post loop scoop up of the remaining items if it is not a multiple of 9

Answer (score 7):

As a general strategy I would not worry about efficiency at first.

Code it as explicitly as possible, and then write a load of unit tests confirming it works. The iteratively improve performance.

Its easier to make correct code fast than it is to make fast code correct.

Comment: +1 For "Its easier to make correct code fast than it is to make fast code correct."

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < ##; i++){if(i%3==0){startNewArray}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy, you can do it in the following way....
It is code snippet below....

byte[] YourBigArray = new byte[SomeValue];

int temp = 0;

while(temp < YourBigArray.size - 1 )
{
    System.arrayCopy(YourBigArray, temp, smallarray, 0, 3);
    temp+=3;
}

Try this code and also see the documentation of arrayCopy function....

Enjoy.....